# Minting ERC20 token fails because of zero address even though address is non-zero

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, contract-deployment, solidity-0.8.x

I'm building an ERC20 token using OpenZeppelin's ERC20 contract. My token constructor looks like this:

```
    constructor()
        ERC20(
            "Token",
            "TKN"
        )
        Ownable()
    {
        require(msg.sender != address(0), "Cannot deploy from zero address");
        _mint(msg.sender, 18000000000000);
    }
```

When I try to deploy this contract to my local Ganache testnet using truffle, I receive the following error:

```
ERC20: mint to the zero address
```

Upon further investigation, I found that this error is thrown inside the ERC20 contract provided by OpenZeppelin. That's why I added that `require` statement in the constructor.

Weirdly, the constructor does not fail, which means `msg.sender` is *not* the Zero address. So why can't I mint the token?

*(Solidity ^0.8.0)*

Comment: Can you perhaps post a link to the entire contract?

Comment: @hrkrshnn I figured it out, the problem is that I was minting tokens for miners and Ganache provides a 0 address for `block.coinbase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was totally my bad: Not visible in the sample I provided is some code that mints a small amount of tokens to the miner of the block. (Not sure why (it was a long time ago)).

On the blockchain, this would have worked just fine, but I was testing locally using truffle's Ganache. Because Ganache is only a test blockchain, there are no miners, and therefore the address `block.coinbase`, which usually corresponds to the miner's address, is always `0`.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works if I declare the msg.sender as a address variable at the start of my constructor

```
contract Test is ERC20{

address public OWNER;
uint private _totalSupply = 500000;

constructor() ERC20("Test Token ERC20", "T20"){
    
    OWNER = msg.sender;
    _mint(OWNER, _totalSupply);

}

}
```

Comment: Already solved it: [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/100165/minting-erc20-token-fails-because-of-zero-address-even-though-address-is-non-zer/118759#comment122499_100165). It was just an issue with my environment there's nothing actually wrong with the code

Comment: @Jake Nice work there! Can you add that explanation as an answer? So the question can be marked as resolved. Thank you!